# Excel Reference Other Sheets without changing on move

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, cell, vlookup

I have an Excel workbook which has multiple sheets. On sheet 3 I want to reference selected columns on sheet 1. This works doing =sheet1!A1 and so on, but when users remove an entire row, the reference follows the row. So now the reference is =sheet2!A1.

How do I get this to be a explicit reference? I have seen posts suggesting index, vlookup etc.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute reference. E.g. `=Sheet1!$A$1`

You can also only fixate the column, by doing `=Sheet1!$A1` or only fixate the row `=Sheet1!A$1`

You can type the dollar sign manually or just press the F4 button on your keyboard.